# Modifying open source project while incorporating remote changes with Git

Tags: git

I had git cloned the MapBox-ios-sdk project. I've made a few ugly hack changes to the code that was not appropriate to contribute back. But MapBox-ios-sdk changed recently. If I want to merge their latest changes to my project while still maintaining my hack, what's the best practice about doing that with Git? Should I have branched initially when I cloned? Or should I just modify in the master branch and just git pull from the official source and resolve conflict, and keep it at that for future sdk version as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your hack has been committed to your local `master` branch. You can move it to a branch by doing something like:

```
git branch -m master myhack
git branch myhack^ master
```

This will give you a `myhack` branch with your one commit on it (adjust `myhack^` if there is more than one commit), and a `master` branch that matches the original master from the project.

At this point, you can pull new code into your local `master` branch without conflict. Then, switch to your `myhack` branch and merge the new master in:

```
git checkout myhack
git merge master
```

Comment: I've never made any commit my local master branch. I've only modified the code in place. What's the character "^"? And I'm not sure what you mean by "adjust `myhack^` if there is more than one commit.

Comment: Oh, well if you haven't made any commits at all yet, then it's even easier. Do `git checkout -b myhack` and then commit your changes on your new `myhack` branch. Then follow the instructions starting from "At this point..."

Comment: As for your other questions, I see you're very new to Git. The notation `myhack^` means "the commit *before* `myhack`". If you were to have made more than one commit, then there are other notations for describing an earlier commit. See the friendly Git documentation.

Comment: Yes I do not have any extensive use of any source control so I don't mess with commit. Git workflow is also confusing. What's the advantage of having my own myhack branch and merge the master in the local, versus just hacking and committing on the local master branch and pull in the remote master branch?

Comment: Having your own private branch allows you to keep your changes better separated from the upstream repository. Without a private branch, your changes don't have a name, get all muddled in with the upstream changes, and your `master` branch ends up being *different* from the upstream `master` branch. In Git, branches are super lightweight and creating new branches for this purpose is totally normal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't branch first, your best course of action is what you described: *modify in the master branch and just git pull from the official source and resolve conflict*.